# Eclipse reverts perspective on startup

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Every time I start up Eclipse (Juno SR2), it reverts to the Java EE perspective, regardless of what perspective I was using before. When I add and switch back the the Java perspective, it has also reset all my windows (Search, JUnit etc.), and all my opened files has been closed as well.

We are a few people here who experience the same problems. Does anyone know how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up your perspective and configure it as you want it, and then select **Window > Save Perspective As...** Give the perspective a name and press OK.

Then go to **Window > Preferences > General > Perspectives**

Find your newly saved perspective in the list, select it and then press **Make Default**.

Comment: Hmm, it works, but not that long ago, Eclipse was capable of remembering the location of its windows by itself.